# How to get transactionID & receipt from MKStoreKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I've implemented [MKStoreKit](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit) successfully and get notifications successfully after purchasing.
I need to get transactionID & receipt simply but I'm not sure how to get transactionID & receipt from response parameter `note`.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:kMKStoreKitProductPurchasedNotification
      object:nil
       queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
  usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
      NSLog(@"Purchased/Subscribed to product with id: %@", [note object]);
  }];
```

I get my IAP `productID` from `note` parameter, when it is purchased successfully but seems like it doesn't include transactionID & receipt.
I'm pretty sure the callback block should return necessary informations including transactionID & receipt.

Do I think wrong or this library doesn't support this feature?

Comment: It's not clear what result you see,

Comment: I've updated the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling, I finally went to [RMStore](https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore) instead of MKStoreKit.

Here are some of my codes.

```
[[RMStore defaultStore] addPayment:"YOUR_IAP_PRODUCT_ID" success:^(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction) {
        NSString* transactionID = transaction.transactionIdentifier;
        NSString* receipt = @"";
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[RMStore receiptURL]];
        if(data != nil ) {
            receipt = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions: 0];
        }

    } failure:^(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Something went wrong");
    }];
```